# SVG linearGradient doesn't work at a certain smaller window size

Tags: reactjs, svg, next.js, linear-gradients, window-resize

I have an SVG that uses linearGradient in its paths' fill properties. Works fine on desktop view but as I resize the window, the fill goes blank/is no longer linked to the gradient definition. Any idea why that would happen?

Using React and Next.js, tested on Chrome and Edge (unable to test on other browsers due to an unrelated bug involving the auth system on the project im working on)

Here's my SVG:

```
<svg
          version="1.1"
          id="menu"
          className={this.hasActiveItem() ? "has-active-item" : ""}
          xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
          viewBox="-15 50 730 730"
          
        >
          <defs>
            <linearGradient
            xlinkHref="#a"
              id="a"
              x1={515.81}
              x2={154.31}
              y1={532.6}
              y2={153.1}
              gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse"
            >
              <stop offset={0.22} stopColor="#0495b7" />
              <stop offset={1} stopColor="#0071bb" />
            </linearGradient>
            <linearGradient
            xlinkHref="#g"
              id="g"
              x1={98.15}
              x2={570.5}
              y1={251.62}
              y2={432.54}
              gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse"
            >
              <stop offset={0} stopColor="#e5e5e5" stopOpacity={0.8} />
              <stop offset={1} stopColor="gray" stopOpacity={0.7} />
            </linearGradient>
            <linearGradient
            xlinkHref="#f"
              id="f"
              x1={321.48}
              x2={85.23}
              y1={263.58}
              y2={156.33}
              gradientTransform="rotate(-45 197.667 207.374)"
              gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse"
            >
              <stop offset={0} stopColor="#033" />
              <stop offset={0.68} stopColor="#165d6d" />
            </linearGradient>
            <linearGradient
            xlinkHref="#e"
              id="e"
              x1={47.74}
              x2={278.53}
              y1={399.86}
              y2={518.11}
              gradientTransform="rotate(-45 197.669 476.683)"
              gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse"
            >
              <stop offset={0} stopColor="#39b44a" />
              <stop offset={0.85} stopColor="#006837" />
            </linearGradient>
            <linearGradient
              id="d"
              x1={305.39}
              x2={558.14}
              y1={419.36}
              y2={507.11}
              gradientTransform="rotate(-45 470.487 476.678)"
              gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse"
            >
              <stop offset={0} stopColor="#8bc53f" />
              <stop offset={1} stopColor="#5b7710" />
            </linearGradient>
            <linearGradient
            xlinkHref="#c"
              id="c"
              x1={596.55}
              x2={324.3}
              y1={255.05}
              y2={150.8}
              gradientTransform="rotate(-45 470.748 206.87)"
              gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse"
            >
              <stop offset={0} stopColor="#165d6d" />
              <stop offset={0.73} stopColor="#12949b" />
            </linearGradient>
            <linearGradient
              xlinkHref="#a"
              id="b"
              x1={197.3}
              x2={472.23}
              y1={342.52}
              y2={342.52}
            />
            <style>{".cls-2{fill:#fff}"}</style>
          </defs>
          <g
            data-name="Layer 2"
            style={{
              isolation: "isolate",
            }}
          >
            <g data-name="Layer 1">
              <g id="evaluation-data">
                <a
                  className={`item ${this.checkActive(menus[1].id)}`}
                  id="item-1"
                  role="link"
                  tabIndex="0"
                  xlinkTitle={`${menus[1].title}`}
                  transform="matrix(1,0,0,1,0,0)"
                  data-svg-origin="250 250"
                  onClick={this.handler.bind(
                    this,
                    menus[1].id,
                    `${menus[1].slug}`
                  )}
                >
                  <circle
                    cx={334.32}
                    cy={342.08}
                    r={252.46}
                    style={{
                      fill: "url(#a)",
                      stroke: "url(#g)",
                      strokeWidth: ".75px",
                      strokeMiterlimit: 10,
                    }}
                  />
                  <path
                    d="m335.74 251.96 8.82-154.33-2.21 154.57 19.81-153.31-13.23 154.01 30.69-151.5-24.18 152.68 41.42-148.93-35.01 150.56 51.94-145.59-45.66 147.68 62.2-141.51-56.09 144.05 72.14-136.72-66.22 139.68 81.7-131.22-76.01 134.59 90.86-125.05-85.43 128.83 99.55-118.26-94.39 122.41 107.73-110.86-102.89 115.37 115.36-102.89-110.85 107.73 122.41-94.39-118.26 99.54 128.83-85.42-125.06 90.86 134.6-76.02-131.22 81.71 139.68-66.22-136.72 72.13 144.05-56.08-141.52 62.2 147.68-45.67-145.59 51.95 150.56-35.02-148.92 41.43 152.67-24.19-151.5 30.7 154.01-13.23-153.3 19.81 154.56-2.21-154.32 8.82 154.32 8.82-154.56-2.21 153.3 19.81-154.01-13.23 151.5 30.7-152.67-24.19 148.92 41.43-150.56-35.02 145.59 51.95-147.68-45.67 141.52 62.2-144.05-56.09 136.72 72.14-139.68-66.22 131.22 81.71-134.6-76.02 125.06 90.86-128.83-85.42 118.26 99.54-122.41-94.39 110.85 107.73-115.36-102.89 102.89 115.37L396.44 414.7l94.39 122.41-99.55-118.26 85.43 128.83-90.86-125.05 76.01 134.59L380.16 426l66.22 139.68-72.14-136.72 56.09 144.05-62.2-141.51 45.66 147.68-51.94-145.59 35.01 150.56-41.42-148.93 24.18 152.68-30.69-151.5 13.23 154.01-19.81-153.31 2.21 154.57-8.82-154.33-8.83 154.33 2.21-154.57-19.81 153.31 13.23-154.01-30.69 151.5 24.18-152.68-41.42 148.93 35.01-150.56-51.94 145.59 45.66-147.68-62.19 141.51 56.08-144.05-72.13 136.72L291.31 426l-81.7 131.22 76.01-134.59-90.85 125.05 85.42-128.83-99.55 118.26 94.4-122.41-107.73 110.86 102.88-115.37-115.36 102.89 110.86-107.73-122.41 94.39 118.25-99.54-128.83 85.42 125.06-90.86-134.6 76.02 131.22-81.71-139.67 66.22 136.71-72.14-144.04 56.09 141.51-62.2-147.68 45.67 145.59-51.95-150.56 35.02 148.92-41.43-152.67 24.19 151.5-30.7-154.01 13.23 153.3-19.81-154.56 2.21 154.33-8.82-154.33-8.82 154.56 2.21-153.3-19.81 154.01 13.23-151.5-30.7 152.67 24.19-148.92-41.43 150.56 35.02-145.59-51.95 147.68 45.67-141.51-62.2 144.04 56.08-136.71-72.13 139.67 66.22-131.22-81.71 134.6 76.02-125.06-90.86 128.83 85.42-118.25-99.54 122.41 94.39-110.86-107.73 115.36 102.89-102.88-115.37L275.04 274.6l-94.4-122.41 99.55 118.26-85.42-128.83 90.85 125.05-76.01-134.59 81.7 131.22-66.21-139.68 72.13 136.72-56.08-144.05 62.19 141.51-45.66-147.68 51.94 145.59-35.01-150.56 41.42 148.93-24.18-152.68 30.69 151.5-13.23-154.01 19.81 153.31-2.21-154.57z"
                    style={{
                      fill: "#0495b7",
                      mixBlendMode: "screen",
                      opacity: 0.17,
                    }}
                  />
                  <path
                    d="M297.84 122.65V106h5.78c5.04 0 8.12 3.98 8.12 8.33 0 5.09-3.22 8.33-8.48 8.33h-5.42zm5.33-2.23c3.85 0 6.14-2.25 6.14-6.05s-2.63-6.14-6.03-6.14h-3.02v12.2h2.9zM324.57 122.65v-1.94h-.04c-.88 1.49-2.45 2.25-4.23 2.25-3.65 0-6.62-2.75-6.62-6.35 0-3.98 2.86-6.77 6.53-6.77 1.82 0 3.35.67 4.32 2.09h.04v-1.76h2.34v12.47h-2.34Zm.04-6.21c0-2.43-1.76-4.46-4.34-4.46-2.34 0-4.25 2-4.25 4.46s1.91 4.39 4.25 4.39 4.34-2.03 4.34-4.39ZM330.28 122.65v-10.33h-1.69v-2.14h1.69v-4.19h2.34v4.19h2.05v2.14h-2.05v10.33h-2.34zM346.46 122.65v-1.94h-.04c-.88 1.49-2.45 2.25-4.23 2.25-3.65 0-6.62-2.75-6.62-6.35 0-3.98 2.86-6.77 6.53-6.77 1.82 0 3.35.67 4.32 2.09h.04v-1.76h2.34v12.47h-2.34Zm.04-6.21c0-2.43-1.76-4.46-4.34-4.46-2.34 0-4.25 2-4.25 4.46s1.91 4.39 4.25 4.39 4.34-2.03 4.34-4.39ZM367.59 120.04c-1.33 2-2.93 2.93-4.84 2.93-2.81 0-5.09-2.16-5.09-4.97 0-2.05 1.12-3.83 3.2-4.75-1.24-1.24-1.6-2.16-1.6-3.31 0-2.32 1.73-4.25 4.21-4.25 2.34 0 4.14 1.89 4.14 4.23 0 1.78-.97 3.13-2.79 4.01l2.21 2.16 1.82-3.67h2.63l-2.72 5.49 3.35 3.42-1.62 1.64-2.9-2.93Zm-5.13-5.15c-1.42.47-2.36 1.53-2.36 3.08s1.1 2.77 2.66 2.77c1.28 0 2.34-.7 3.22-2.39l-3.51-3.47Zm2.72-5.04c0-1.06-.74-1.94-1.73-1.94s-1.76.85-1.76 2.03c0 .79.45 1.49 1.42 2.36 1.6-.81 2.07-1.46 2.07-2.45ZM278.42 142.15V125.5h8.98v2.23h-6.55v4.91h6.55v2.23h-6.55v5.06h6.55v2.23h-8.98zM293.88 142.15l-4.95-12.47h2.5l3.26 8.91h.04l3.2-8.91h2.5l-4.91 12.47h-1.64zM311.99 142.15v-1.94h-.04c-.88 1.49-2.45 2.25-4.23 2.25-3.65 0-6.62-2.75-6.62-6.35 0-3.98 2.86-6.77 6.53-6.77 1.82 0 3.35.67 4.32 2.09h.04v-1.76h2.34v12.47h-2.34Zm.04-6.21c0-2.43-1.76-4.46-4.34-4.46-2.34 0-4.25 2-4.25 4.46s1.91 4.39 4.25 4.39 4.34-2.03 4.34-4.39ZM317.44 142.15V125.5h2.34v16.65h-2.34zM331.66 142.15v-1.35h-.04c-.61 1.06-2.03 1.67-3.67 1.67-2.68 0-5.2-1.44-5.2-5.83v-6.95h2.34v6.77c0 2.61.97 3.87 3.11 3.87s3.26-1.51 3.26-3.92v-6.73h2.34v12.47h-2.14ZM347.03 142.15v-1.94h-.04c-.88 1.49-2.45 2.25-4.23 2.25-3.65 0-6.62-2.75-6.62-6.35 0-3.98 2.86-6.77 6.53-6.77 1.82 0 3.35.67 4.32 2.09h.04v-1.76h2.34v12.47h-2.34Zm.05-6.21c0-2.43-1.76-4.46-4.34-4.46-2.34 0-4.25 2-4.25 4.46s1.91 4.39 4.25 4.39 4.34-2.03 4.34-4.39ZM352.74 142.15v-10.33h-1.69v-2.14h1.69v-4.19h2.34v4.19h2.05v2.14h-2.05v10.33h-2.34zM358.68 128.24v-2.75h2.34v2.75h-2.34zm0 13.91v-12.47h2.34v12.47h-2.34zM370 142.47c-3.51 0-6.64-2.99-6.64-6.5 0-3.8 2.99-6.62 6.82-6.62 3.44 0 6.68 2.7 6.64 6.66-.04 3.33-2.84 6.46-6.82 6.46Zm.07-10.98c-2.34 0-4.37 1.98-4.37 4.41s1.96 4.43 4.32 4.43 4.46-1.94 4.46-4.46-1.96-4.39-4.41-4.39ZM387.88 142.15v-6.8c0-2.63-1.04-3.87-3.11-3.87s-3.29 1.51-3.29 3.85v6.82h-2.34v-12.47h2.18v1.33h.04c.92-1.19 2.21-1.67 3.65-1.67 2.99 0 5.2 1.89 5.2 5.33v7.47h-2.34Z"
                    className="cls-2"
                  />
                </a>
              </g>
            </g>
            <g id="student-recruitment">
              <a
                className={`item ${this.checkActive(menus[2].id)}`}
                id="item-6"
                role="link"
                tabIndex="0"
                xlinkTitle={`${menus[2].title}`}
                onClick={this.handler.bind(
                  this,
                  menus[2].id,
                  `${menus[2].slug}`
                )}
              >
                <rect
                  width={185.77}
                  height={185.77}
                  x={104.78}
                  y={114.49}
                  rx={39.46}
                  ry={39.46}
                  style={{
                    fill: "url(#f)",
                    strokeMiterlimit: 10,
                    stroke: "#fff",
                    strokeWidth: ".94px",
                  }}
                  transform="rotate(45 197.663 207.375)"
                />
                <path
                  d="M152.3 202.27v-15.54h4.43c3.27 0 5.35 1.66 5.35 4.7s-2.04 4.7-5.33 4.7h-2.22v6.13h-2.22Zm4.43-8.21c1.96 0 3.13-.94 3.13-2.62s-1.21-2.62-3.15-2.62h-2.18v5.25h2.2ZM163.82 202.27v-11.63h2v1.05h.04c.51-.78 1.4-1.28 2.9-1.36v2.25c-1.85.06-2.8 1.22-2.8 3.17v6.53h-2.14ZM175.7 202.56c-3.21 0-6.07-2.79-6.07-6.07 0-3.55 2.74-6.17 6.24-6.17 3.15 0 6.11 2.52 6.07 6.21-.04 3.11-2.59 6.03-6.24 6.03Zm.06-10.25c-2.14 0-3.99 1.85-3.99 4.12s1.79 4.14 3.95 4.14 4.08-1.81 4.08-4.16-1.79-4.09-4.03-4.09ZM193.52 200.74c-.89 1.22-2.31 1.83-3.93 1.83-3.27 0-6.09-2.88-6.09-6.03 0-3.51 2.68-6.21 6.11-6.21 1.48 0 3.05.63 3.95 1.66v-1.34h2.14v10.1c0 3.78-2.29 6.11-6.15 6.11-2.61 0-4.67-1.41-5.64-3.67h2.39c.8 1.15 1.87 1.68 3.27 1.68 2.61 0 3.99-1.45 3.99-4.12h-.04Zm.04-4.28c0-2.73-2.04-4.14-4.01-4.14-2.12 0-3.91 1.87-3.91 4.14s1.81 4.12 3.93 4.12c2.49 0 3.99-2.23 3.99-4.12ZM198.42 202.27v-11.63h2v1.05h.04c.51-.78 1.4-1.28 2.9-1.36v2.25c-1.85.06-2.8 1.22-2.8 3.17v6.53h-2.14ZM214.18 202.27v-1.81h-.04c-.8 1.39-2.24 2.1-3.87 2.1-3.33 0-6.05-2.56-6.05-5.92 0-3.72 2.61-6.32 5.97-6.32 1.67 0 3.07.63 3.95 1.95h.04v-1.64h2.14v11.63h-2.14Zm.04-5.79c0-2.27-1.61-4.16-3.97-4.16-2.14 0-3.89 1.87-3.89 4.16s1.75 4.09 3.89 4.09 3.97-1.89 3.97-4.09ZM234.17 202.27v-6.51c0-2.2-.91-3.44-2.7-3.44-1.89 0-2.72 1.07-2.72 3.4v6.55h-2.14v-6.76c0-2.29-1.05-3.19-2.59-3.19-1.89 0-2.82 1.13-2.82 3.42v6.53h-2.14v-11.63h1.98v1.26h.04c.93-1.11 1.79-1.57 3.27-1.57s2.96.73 3.54 1.95c.82-1.32 1.96-1.95 3.77-1.95 2.96 0 4.65 1.89 4.65 4.89v7.05h-2.14ZM171.46 224.02v-15.54h8.21v2.08h-5.99v4.58h5.99v2.08h-5.99v4.72h5.99v2.08h-8.21zM190.14 224.02v-6.34c0-2.46-.95-3.61-2.84-3.61s-3 1.41-3 3.59v6.36h-2.14v-11.63h2v1.24h.04c.84-1.11 2.02-1.55 3.33-1.55 2.74 0 4.75 1.76 4.75 4.98v6.97h-2.14ZM195.25 224.02v-9.64h-1.54v-1.99h1.54v-3.91h2.14v3.91h1.87v1.99h-1.87v9.64h-2.14zM200.68 224.02v-11.63h2v1.05h.04c.51-.78 1.4-1.28 2.9-1.36v2.25c-1.85.06-2.8 1.22-2.8 3.17v6.53h-2.14ZM209.78 227.9l1.67-4.12-4.55-11.4h2.31l3.36 9.03 3.44-9.03h2.31l-6.3 15.52h-2.22z"
                  className="cls-2"
                />
              </a>
            </g>

[... the rest of the svg ...]

        </svg>
```

Tried changing view sizes, blend modes, positions, etc. Tried attaching gradients in classes. Tried hacking a gradient via svg image pattern primitive (that also becomes unlinked on re-size)

When I use a regular color hex code in-line (like fill: "#FFF"), everything is fine. Only when I link to the definition, it breaks (like fill: url(#f))

As far as I know, there are no styles or classes that are attached to this svg anywhere other than within the svg itself.

Comment: Why are you linking the gradients to themselves. Such a circular link is pointless. Maybe that's the cause of your problem.